# Bootstrap datepicker time picker input text

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

I'd like to use [this datetime picker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) but I don't like the way to choose the time. Do you know if it's possible to change the span where the hours and minutes are display to an input text to write with the keyboard the time ?

Answer (score 0):

Only for Time use this one

```
$(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
                    format: 'LT'
                });
```

Only for date :

```
$(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
                    format: 'dd-mm-yy'                      //you can use altformat 
                });
```

Comment: This will not change the way to select the hours and minutes. I just want to replace the hours and minutes span to an input text to enter my hours and minutes with my keyboard